# how to opening layout xml files in Android Layout Editor?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, eclipse-plugin

when I open my layout xml files its opening with default xml editor how to change it to Android Layout Editor without right click and open with option.

problem happens when I try to updated my android sdk and eclipse plugins to `iceCream Sandwitch(ICS)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Window->Preferences->General->Editors->File Associations and set your default editor there.

Comment: This will make any XML file open in the layout editor, which doesn't work for the other xml files in Android projects.  I also started having this issue once I upgraded to the 4.0 SDK.  Is there a fix so it opens the right editor for the different android files?

Comment: You can right click, choose Open With, and pick the Android Layout editor from amongst all the special Android XML editors. However, if it's not opening that by default, this will result in a layout editor that is useless. It seems to be an issue with the latest plugin (15.0.1.)

Comment: @Rohan, Thanks buddy !  you saved me from irritating problem

Answer (score 2):

This happened with my ADT plugin (version v21.1.0-569685).  I found that there were two tabs *underneath* the XML.  The tab with text "filename.xml" was selected, and when I selected the "Graphical Layout" tab, this brought me back to the layout editor.