# Graphical layout missing for Layout XML Files

Tags: android

I installed new SDK for android development. Now when I open Layout XML file for editing..its not showing Graphical Layout tab along with source. Its showing Design and Source tab.

I am not able to view graphical layout.

[image: Before updating SDK]

[image: Updated SDK Issue]

Regards,

Android IT

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966734/how-to-opening-layout-xml-files-in-android-layout-editor

Comment: I am facing the same Problem. And have solve the issue. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708574/how-to-get-the-graphical-layout-window-back-in-eclipse-for-android-application-d/7708805#7708805

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens to me occasionally. I just right click the xml layout file and choose "Open With... Android Layout Editor". It seems to then fix itself until the next time.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on your Eclipse at : Window-->Preferences-->Editors-->File Associations-->.*XML--->set this as Default one---->ok

Comment: Thanks, I set .xml file default editor to Android layout Editor. Its showing the Graphical Layout tab now but showing noting in that. Layout and Palette thing is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

> Delete project, without deleting the source files
>
> File>Import>Existing Projects into Workspace,and select your project

**problem fixed!**

Answer (score 0):

Exact problem is described [here](http://goo.gl/uXKqy).

**Solution:** 
Right click on XML file, select **`open with -> Android Layout Editor`**.

Answer (score 0):

Just Do it.

Right click on the XMLcode layout and then select opneWith Layout editor. It will show the Graphical Layout Editor for your Application and now you are able to see the GrapgicalLayout on Your every Application that have coded by XML code.

Enjoy. . :)

Answer (score 0):

Another "fix" is to copy everything in the .xml to clipboard, then delete everything in the file, add some item in graphical view(should work now), then go back to ext editor and paste your old layout.

sounds stupid, but works sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

"Right click on XML file, select open with -> Android Layout Editor."

In my case it not working.

new soluzion: create new project in new workspace.

Comment: you should post in comment.