# Android project Eclipse issue

Tags: android, eclipse

So I started a new android project in my default workspace. Then I decided to copy the project to another folder and imported the android project. Now when I start Eclipse, I switch the workspace to point to this new folder.

What I'm experimenting now is that eclipse seem no longer to regenerate the R.java values. Also the designer of my layout doesn't display the designer at all .....

How can I fix this?

Comment: oh thanks that worked for R.java files. But would you know why there is no more designer support for my layout.xml files ?

Comment: exactly can you tell me what happen when you open xml file?

Comment: For layout xml files, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7992413/379693

Comment: @Dr.nik : When I open the xml. There is 2 tab the Design and xml. In the Design, all i see is kind of a hierarchy with key-value pair for each property set on the xml.

Comment: @pdiddy can you take a screen short and let me know...

Comment: It's resolved thanks, I had the same issue as the answer Paresh posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### clean the project

when ever you are copy project, some time r.java not genrate so  you need to clean project. so it will generate properly.

Answer (score 2):

***Do the following ...***

**1:**  **default.properties** or **project.properties** is present in your project?
if **project.properties** is present then rename to **default.properties**

**2:** Clean your project and restart your eclips.

Hope this will helps you...Enjoy