# Trying to view my XML in "Graphical Layout" Tab

Tags: xml, eclipse, android-layout

I've been playing around with XML trying to get buttons lined up by changing the int. values and then seeing how it looks on my phone. I've tried to get the XML to show up on my "Graphical Layout" tab on Eclipse with no success. Do I need to add something to the XML file to get it to display on the "Graphical Layout" tab or is this some kind of settings error on my eclipse?

I've already tried all the solutions on @ this link: [Graphical layout missing for Layout XML Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992036/graphical-layout-missing-for-layout-xml-files)

Here is the XML file in question and here is a screen shot of what I'm seeing: http://snag.gy/6H0v6.jpg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/persona_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/persona_marquee"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:textColor="#f0f0f0f0"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="gone" >
</TextView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/persona_img"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/persona_misctxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" >
</TextView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/persona_scorebox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/your_score"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/rate_star_big_on" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/rate_star_big_on" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/rate_star_big_on" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/persona_star4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/rate_star_big_on"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/persona_halfstar4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/rate_star_big_half"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/persona_star5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/rate_star_big_on"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/persona_halfstar5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/rate_star_big_half"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/persona_star5empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/rate_star_big_off"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/textbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/persona_nametxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="7dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/persona_desctxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="14sp" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/persona_statbars"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statlabel1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/statbar1" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/persona_statbar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/statlabel1"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/statlabel1"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:maxHeight="15dip"
        android:minHeight="15dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:progress="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/redprogress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statlabel2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/statlabel1"
        android:layout_below="@id/statlabel1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/statbar2" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/persona_statbar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/statlabel2"
        android:layout_below="@id/persona_statbar1"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/statlabel2"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:maxHeight="15dip"
        android:minHeight="15dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:progress="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/redprogress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statlabel3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/statlabel2"
        android:layout_below="@id/statlabel2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/statbar3" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/persona_statbar3"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/statlabel3"
        android:layout_below="@id/persona_statbar2"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/statlabel3"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:maxHeight="15dip"
        android:minHeight="15dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:progress="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/redprogress" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/lovemeter"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </TextView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:maxHeight="35dip"
        android:minHeight="35dip"
        android:progress="1"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/redprogress" >
    </ProgressBar>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/again_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/again"
    android:textColor="#f0f0f0f0"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</Button>

<com.hookedmediagroup.wasabi.TearRatingView
    android:id="@+id/wasabi_tear_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</com.hookedmediagroup.wasabi.TearRatingView>
```

Answer (score 2):

See my question and answer here: [How to get the graphical layout Window back in Eclipse for Android Application Design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708574/how-to-get-the-graphical-layout-window-back-in-eclipse-for-android-application-d)

It will be the Sollution for your question.

Enjoy. :))

Comment: Have you got the Sollution ? If not then let me inform. and if you got the Sollution then accept the answer. So it can helps other.

Comment: Then please put the screen shot of your isuue.

Comment: @user1181977 : i am not getting what you want. if you are not getting the Layout then click on the Different layout as you want. Ex. click on Layouts or From Widgets or any other option. If still it not solve your issue then click on the Custom and Library Views and press Refresh button.

Comment: @Please leave comment what you want.

Comment: Here is a screen shot, and the tab that corresponds with it is the persona_view.xml, which is in the OP http://snag.gy/2sVpx.jpg

I just want to be able to see what my programmer has coded without installing the apk to my phone every single time.

Comment: Ok. Now do as i have said. May be it solve your issue. Select the Tab that appear like --------- which is right side of the Daytime and select any theme there. then see what happend. If it not solve then reply me again.

Answer (score 0):

edit the visibility line under `TextView` as follows:

```
android:visibility="visible"
```

Instead of

```
android:visibility="gone"
```