# Android XML editors broken in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, adt

Until today (I have no idea what I did to cause this), if I double-clicked an android XML file, then the correct editor would appear.

For example, double-clicking a layout file would open a Graphical Layout tab and a tab with the XML contents for direct editing (named as the file being edited). Now all I get is a Design and a Source tab!

I am unable to preview the layouts I am editing (this is the same as here: [Graphical Layout tab does not appear for some layout files into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715802/graphical-layout-tab-does-not-appear-for-some-layout-files-into-eclipse))

That link also gives a 'workaround' in that I can right-click the file and open with the right editor, but this isn't a solution!

How can I sort this permenantly? I have re-installed fresh Eclipse, ADT to no avail (haven't used fresh SDK... will that matter??).

** Note this happens to all Android XML files, not just layout ones I mentioned above! **

Comment: I hadn't checked the AndroidManifest.xml file, but this opens correctly! :S

Comment: refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966734/how-to-opening-layout-xml-files-in-android-layout-editor

Comment: All applicable Android Editors are present in the 'Associated Editors' list for *.xml. The non-Android ones say they are locked. Do I need to make one a default? Will this not then cause other Android XML files to also open with the same default editor (i.e. menu.xml opening with layout editor)?

Comment: It appears that Eclipse 'remembers' what I opened the file with so next time (having done the right-click thing) it opens correctly... a pain to have to go through all files though!

Comment: And they show the file with X in it icon rather than the correct Android file icon....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this may be a permanent solution:

1. Select any XML layout file
2. click on **`Window->Preferences`** menu.
3. Follow steps as mentioned in attached image.

[image]

Comment: What is the final step?? To lick default? Will this not make all Android XML files open with the Android Layout Editor (such as menu XML files)?

Answer (score 0):

What I had to end up doing was selecting the `Legacy Android Xml Resources Editor` from the same list that Paresh is showing and setting it as the default.  I had to choose it from the list that appears when you click the add button.  After that I restarted eclipse and everything was fine.