# Android GUI Layouts in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface, layout

I am very new to Android development and am having some trouble. I am creating an XML file using Eclipse, both the Graphical Layout feature is what I'm having trouble with.

Also, I am working in Android 2.3 for compatibility reasons.

I am wondering if there is a layout which enables me to place buttons or text fields or any attribute where I want to put them. This may sound stupid, but it seems that every layout has some sort of order in which it lets you add attributes, and whenever I try to drag them elsewhere on the layout things just get very very messy.

Comment: You mean you want to take one button and place it anywhere you want. Right?

Comment: Android Layout Editor http://stackoverflow.com/q/7966734/1012284

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is an AbsoluteLayout, this has been deprecated since Android 2 (IIRC). You can try using the RelativeLayout, which let you position freely your widgets. Else, if you only use LinearLayout, then yes the widget will be positioned in a strict way.

Comment: Sorry, new to the website didn't even realize I could do that :D

Answer (score 1):

use Relative Layout. I recommend that you read up on Android layouts so you understand why, what and hows of Android way. There are some good tutorials that I found helpful. [TutsPlus: Android Layouts](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-layout/)

There is also a very good video from Marakana.
[Marakana: Android Bootcamp](http://marakana.com/training/android/android_bootcamp.html)

If you are just starting out with Android check other tutorials/videos on Marakana. They are a very good resource for beginners.